Cannot figure out why this particular line is messing up the C# xml deserializer
I have verified with multiple XML validators to ensure the document is sound.
In one area of the document, anything after it the C# debugger will say the first character of the next line (after indent; did try having the entire document with none as well) is not formatted correctly:

System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (11, 5).
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Here is the reader/deserialize part of the code:
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VehicleModelInfo));

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    try
    {
        return (VehicleModelInfo) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        // [...]
    }
}

This is the problematic line:
<PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage value="0.000000" />

It, along with the other elements in the XML, are declared:
[XmlElement("PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage")]
public float PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage { get; set; }

I cannot figure out why this one (there are many other float values in the XML) in particular is not behaving.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Your setup using [XmlElement("PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage")] requires that the xml data needs to look like below one.
<PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage>0.000000<PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage>

But it doesn't; instead, <PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage value="0.000000" /> is an xml element with the value you are looking for in an attribute named value.
In order to deserialize that one, your VehicleModelInfomodel needs a PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage property to a type having such a Value property, for example:
public class VehicleModelInfo
{ 
    public PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage { get; set; }
} 

public class PovCameraVerticalAdjustmentForRollCage
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public float Value { get; set; }
}


OK that should get me started. Another one is doing a similar thing now so I'll just have to figure out which ones are not behaving like the others are. Thanks!
